# Unable to insert data into postgresql table using flat file with copy command

Tags: postgresql

My table structure is

```
company=# \d address
            Table "public.address"
  Column  |         Type          | Modifiers
----------+-----------------------+-----------
 name     | character varying(80) |
 age      | integer               |
 dob      | date                  |
 village  | character varying(8)  |
 locality | character varying(80) |
 district | character varying(80) |
 state    | character varying(80) |
 pin      | integer               |
```

and i have following data in the flat file(*.txt file).

```
insert into address(name,age,dob,village,locality,district,state,pin) 
values('David',43,'1972-10-23','Elchuru','Addanki','Prakasam','AP',544421);
insert into address(name,age,dob,village,locality,district,state,pin) 
values('George',53,'1962-10-23','London','London','LN','LN',544421);
insert into address(name,age,dob,village,locality,district,state,pin) 
values('David',28,'1982-10-23','Ongole','Ongole','Prakasam','AP',520421);
```

Now I am trying load into my table 'address' using following query i psql shell.

```
copy address from 'C:/P Files/address_data.txt';
```

Error is:

```
company=# copy address from 'C:/P Files/address_data.txt';
```

> ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(80)
>   CONTEXT:  COPY address, line 1, column name: "insert into address(name,age,dob,village,locality,district,state,pin) values('David',43,'1972-10-23'..."

Please suggest modifications to be done in the above query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a *data* file.  You have a file with a set of commands.

You can use the [`psql` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html) to execute the inserts.

A data file would look more like this:

```
David,43,1972-10-23,Elchuru,Addanki,Prakasam,AP,544421
George,53,1962-10-23,London,London,LN,LN,544421
David,28,1982-10-23,Ongole,Ongole,Prakasam,AP,520421
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon,

I have copied above lines in txt file and run following query. It worked

copy address from 'C:/P Files/address_data.txt'  ( DELIMITER(',') );

Thank you